# Print a table of n*n numbers?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, for-loop

How do I print out a table of numbers when the last number is given by the user, and the variables are added together to get new variables? For example, if the user gives the value 3 for numberOfRows, an example output would be;

```
           1          2          3

1          2          3          4

2          3          4          5

3          4          5          6
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
        int numberOfRows;
        int numberOfVariables = numberOfRows*numberOfRows;
        int i = 0;

        boolean cycle = false;
        if(i < numberOfVariables){
            cycle = true;
            i++;
        } else if(i >= numberOfVariables){
            cycle = false;
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println(cycle);

        for(cycle = true;;){

            System.out.println(i + "\t");
            i++;

        }
```

I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: Someone already done this [**here**](http://ideone.com/AN3Hpf). Check it out

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox That post doesn't address the question.  The question states that the last number is provided by the user.  That post hard-codes the number of rows.

Also, that code is wrong.  It says it should print 3 rows, but it prints 4.

Comment: @A.J. How is the user supplying the last number?  As a cli argument? After a prompt by the program in the commandline?  Some other way?

Comment: @Josiah 1st, it just a sample. second, 4 rows because it includes the header (see the OP's example)

Comment: granted on the second part - input of 3 should print 4 rows - my mistake

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws NumberFormatException,
        IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter number of rows : ");
    int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < n + i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output :
Enter number of rows : 6 
0       1       2       3       4       5
1       2       3       4       5       6
2       3       4       5       6       7
3       4       5       6       7       8
4       5       6       7       8       9
5       6       7       8       9      10

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Wnter row count");
        int numberOfRows = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= numberOfRows ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j <= numberOfRows ; j++) {
                System.out.print(i + j + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Wnter row count
3
0  1  2  3  
1  2  3  4  
2  3  4  5  
3  4  5  6
```